# is this code safe base on happen-first principle

Tags: java

The sample as below: I have two services called A, B. And service A will write database and after that it will call API of service B. Then service B will can consumer database that has been written by service A.

code sample as below:

```json
    //service A
    public void writeDbAndNotifyServiceB() {
        // will need much time to write database
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
            // write db A
        }
        // ddb write finished, call serviceB
        B.readDbWhichServiceAWrite();
    }
```

```
    // API of service B
    public void readDbWhichServiceAWrite() {
        //read db A
    }
```

After I learn something about **instruction re-order**, I have a concern that whether it is possible that

```
        B.readDbWhichServiceAWrite();
```

was executed before write db operation and then Service B cant read anything from database.

And if this case maybe exist, what is the correct solution?

really appreciate if you can give any advice.

Comment: Are you committing the data you write to the database?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you think the database might not have been written to after the loop finishes?

Comment: I dont know whether the call API will be execute first due to  instruction re-order. In this circumstances, they for-loop maybe not executed when service B read database. @kaya3

Answer (score 0):

it is safe.
from jsr133: [http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Epugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf)

> Happens-Before Relationship Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship.
> If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.

> Each action in a thread happens-before every subsequent action in that thread

Comment: I am not sure whether the for-loop must execute before ` B.readDbWhichServiceAWrite();`

Comment: @nailfei Each action in a thread happens-before every subsequent action in that thread